# Microsoft Reporting - Single RDLC to print multiple letters, one for each row in datasource

Tags: c#, webforms, rdlc

We need to print and send letters to correspondents.  We're generating PDFs using:
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport
Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportDataSource.

Each row in the data source contains a name and an address.

***Our Requirement*:**
If there are three rows in the dataset, we want a **single PDF** generated with **three of the same letters (but different names & addresses)**.

Is this fairly doable with Microsoft Reporting?  What's the best approach?
I see where DataSources are valuable for creating tables *within* a report, but what about an entire page generated for each row?

Comment: Well, if you going to generate + use + entertain the idea of  a PDF, then that would NOT be suitable for the email body and text, but would work as a PDF attachment to a email being sent. So, it not really clear why a PDF would be used if the goal is a email say laid out as HTML to be sent? You can lay out a RDLC report with a few fields that are placed thought the page. But, question is goal to "attach" a PDF report to the email or not? Far better (and simple) to use some HTML template in which you have some fields of data inserted throughout HTML. PDF only makes sense as report as attachment

Answer (score 0):

We found a solution:

1. Add a table to the form.
2. Remove ALL but one row and one column, no header
3. Add the appropriate dataset
4. Drag recipient info (name, address) to text boxes on the form.
5. Fill in the rest of the contents of the letter
6. Set proper break points on the outer rectangle

Doing this created three "letters", one to each recipient, and with the same content.
These three letters are now inside one PDF, which is what we needed